# DBD::Oracle How to set v$session.program BEFORE connect

Tags: java, oracle, perl, session

I have to use DBD::Oracle to connect to an Oracle database which has a LOGON trigger which verifies my v$session.program at the time of login.

I have tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

DBI->connect ('dbi:Oracle:host=<ip>;sid=<sid>', 'test', 'TEST', 
    { ora_module_name => 'My Program'}) || die DBI::errstr;
```

BUT this does not work, because DBD::Oracle does not set v$session.program until AFTER the connect.

However, JDBC does support setting before connect, by:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", username);
props.setProperty("password", password);
props.put("v$session.program", "My Program");
Class driver = Class.forName(driverClass);
```

But I'm not using Java.  I'm using Perl.  Any suggestions?!

[UPDATE]

Running "strace" on the process determines that the DBD::Oracle module is doing the following:

open("/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 4
read(4, "perl\0test.pl\0", 255)         = 13

So yes, I could in theory create a script (or soft link) named "My Program" and use that as the command line to run my file.   But that rates pretty high on the "very sad and not nice at all" scale.  :(

Comment: Recommend removing the Java tag as this is purely a Perl and Oracle connection / properties / trigger discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm says

```
PROGRAM     VARCHAR2(48)    Operating system program name
```

It means you should rename somehow your binary to the expected value.

There are a few hints to doing this:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=500714

perldoc perlvar:

```
   $0      Contains the name of the program being executed.

           On some (but not all) operating systems assigning to $0
           modifies the argument area that the "ps" program sees. On some
           platforms you may have to use special "ps" options or a
           different "ps" to see the changes. Modifying the $0 is more
           useful as a way of indicating the current program state than it
           is for hiding the program you're running.
```

...

Comment: Marking as correct.  BUT... actually this isn't really possible.  See my self comment below.